# Python Infinite loop is slowing over time

Tags: python, pandas, generator

I have a function that is part of a much larger infinite.  I have discovered that the function slows the loop to the point that eventually my computer will completely freeze.

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
 
  
def make_fps(d, F, df_f, state, t_start, PHASE, run_num):
    F += 1
    if F < 100:
        fps = np.NaN
        fps_average = np.NaN
    else:
        fps = round(F / (time() - t_start), 2)
        fps_average = np.NaN
    if F > 200:
        fps_average = round(df_f["fps"].mean(), 2)
    df = {'frame number': [F], 'fps': [
        fps], 'fps average': [fps_average], 'state': [state],  'run number': [run_num]}
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
    df_f = df_f.append(df_new)
    print("frame number", F, "fps", fps, "average fps",
            fps_average,  "run number", run_num)
    return df_f, F, fps, run_num, fps_average

df_f = pd.DataFrame()
state = "this is a test"
t_start = time()
d, F, PHASE, run_num = 0,0, 0, 0       

while True:
    df_f, F, fps, run_num, fps_average = make_fps(d, F, df_f, state, t_start, PHASE, run_num)
    print (F, fps, fps_average)
```

I think building the DataFrame is causing issues. Also, would this function benefit from implementing generators?  I am new to python I am unclear how to apply generators correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: please explain what are you tring to do...

Comment: This function is used in a larger application.  The goal is to calculate the speed of the loop (fps), average speed of the loop (fps_average) and build a dataframe that will be later saved to a .cvs file.  Could there be an issue with building the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you passing the same parameters over and over again.
I can not think why it could be a good idea.
But as for your question about generators, just replace `return` with `yield`

Good luck!

Comment: Which parameters are you calling "the same"?  Are you referring to  state, PHASE and run_num?  Those values change in other functions that are part of the final solution.  I should have edited them out for the purpose of this example.   When replacing ```return``` with ```yield``` do I still let the parameters?  For example ```return df_f, F, fps, run_num, fps_average``` becomes ```yield df_f, F, fps, run_num, fps_average``` ?  When I do this get an error.

Comment: `df_f, F, fps, run_num, fps_average = list(make_fps(d, F, df_f, state, t_start, PHASE, run_num))[0]` maybe